# Plotting abundance by food group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, reshape

I have a dataframe with

```
1 col = sample ID 
2 col = bacteria phyla (out of 7 groups)
3 col = bacteria abundance
4 col = fiber category (out of normal, high, low.)
```

I would like to plot this with the different phyla groups as fill, fiber category as the x axis (so 3 bars of high, low and normal) against relative abundance on the y axis.

```
Sample  Phyla           Abundance   FiberCategory
42226   Fusobacteria    0.000007990 Normal
42226   Verrucomicrobia 0.000003990 Normal
42226   Other           0.003485600 Normal
42226   Bacteroidetes   0.403487198 Normal
42226   Firmicutes      0.577910    Normal
42226   Proteobacteria    0.0010    Normal
42226   Actinobacteria     0.0140   Normal
311101  Fusobacteria        0.00    Normal
311101  Verrucomicrobia    0.003    Normal
311101  Other             0.0009    Normal
311101  Proteobacteria  0.000743013 Normal
311101  Bacteroidetes   0.338208944 Normal
311101  Actinobacteria  0.004665200 Normal
311101  Firmicutes         0.654    Normal
4921103 Other        0.000191938    Low
4921103 Fusobacteria    0.000000000 Low
4921103 Actinobacteria  0.000246777 Low
4921103 Proteobacteria  0.007608959 Low
4921103 Verrucomicrobia 0.000004570 Low
4921103 Firmicutes    0.267081313   Low
4921103 Bacteroidetes   0.724866443 Low
```

I have tried `ggplot(vg, aes(x = VegetablesCategory, y = Abundance, fill = Phyla))` but it says the plot is damaged..

Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you did not add any layer to the plot. Also you probably want to aggregate your data by *FiberCategory* and *Phyla*:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

vg %>% group_by(FiberCategory, Phyla) %>% summarise(Abundance = sum(Abundance)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = FiberCategory, y = Abundance, fill = Phyla)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This plot appears with bacteria phyla on the x and fiber category as the fill. I would like the phyla as the fill. Also, the phyla results are not ordered. So the bar goes (green, blue, orange, green again, purple etc..) Is there a way to get the total abundance color groups together? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure we are getting the same plot...I edited to add the picture. Do you get the same? Some of the Phyla simply do not appear because their quantity is too small to be visible compared to Bacteroidetes and Firmicutes.